# Delay request database when keyup (autocomplete)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a textbox, I have using both Timer and DispatcherTimer for delay on keyup, but it not actually as my expected.

Event stil fire when Interval is finish. After 5 seconds, the Fiter event stil fire.

Here are my code:

Init variable

```
DispatcherTimer timerFilter;
//or
//Timer timerFilter = new Timer(5000);
```

Init event

```
InitializeComponent();
timerFiter = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5) };

timerFiter.Tick += (s, args) =>
{
    Filter();
};

//or

//timerFilter.Elapsed += Filter;
```

When key up

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");
timerFilter.Start();
//or
//timerFilter.Enabled = true;
```

When key down

```
Console.WriteLine("Destroy");
timerFiter.Stop();
//or
//timerFilter.Enabled = false;
```

My event

```
private void Filter(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filter");
    timerFiter.Stop();
    //or
    //timerFilter.Enabled = false;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I sorry, this code working good. due I set wrong event keydown for the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a key up event, so the last thing that will happen after the last key press is:

```
Console.WriteLine("Start");
timerFilter.Start();
```

To make sure that your timer stops after the results are filtered, add a Stop call to your Filter handler:

```
private void Filter(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filter");
    timerFilter.Stop();
}
```

Comment: My mean, when I typing on textbox, after 5s event will be call although I typing.

Comment: The DispatcherTimer, unlike the Timer, is "on" by default, so it's probably firing constantly regardless of whether you are typing or not. I always explicitly call `Stop()` on my dispatcher timer instances when I create them.

Comment: Also, try hooking into `PreviewKeyDown` and `PreviewKeyUp` events rather than `KeyDown` and `KeyUp`, as some other handler could be intercepting the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events before they bubble up to your handlers.

Comment: I sorry, my code working good. due I set wrong event keydown on xaml for the textbox. Thanks for help.